# Joining text to form a column name to be used in a table

Tags: string, r, histogram

I'm trying to use a loop to create histograms where the column name reference changes as a result of the loop by changing the string of the column name.  I want to get four histograms for `column1`, `column2`, `column3`, `column4`.  (In my actually example the columns are not named column 1, but I want it to be clear).

```
For (i in 1:4){
  hist( paste("dataset$column" +i )  , main ="title") 
}
```

When I try using paste I get the error that `x` must be numeric, but if I try it using just one as a check like

```
hist( dataset$column1), main = "title")
```

it works fine so its not the data itself.

Comment: Why you don't use `dataset[i]`? `paste` returns a `character` vector and no `numeric` one.

Comment: I don't think you want "title" to be the title for all the histograms, do you?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `apply`

```
set.seed(001)
DF <- data.frame(column1=rnorm(100), 
                 column2=rnorm(100),
                 column3=rnorm(100),
                 column4=rnorm(100))

apply(DF, 2, hist)  # It produces one hist for each column
```

Using a `for` loop

```
for(i in 1:ncol(DF)){
  hist(DF[, paste('column', i, sep='')],
       main=paste('Histogram', i))

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I usually use `lapply()` in these cases. Here's an example where I've also used `gsub()` to pretty up the names a little bit.

```
set.seed(001)
DF <- data.frame(Funky.Name.1 = rnorm(100),
                 Funky.Name.2 = rnorm(100),
                 Whoo.Whoo = rnorm(100),
                 Yee.Haw = rnorm(100))
lapply(names(DF), 
       function(x) hist(DF[, x], main = gsub("\\.", " ", x), xlab="Value"))
```

#### Demo

`par(mfrow = c(2, 2))` makes it so we can plot four plots together in a 2x2 grid filled in by row.

```
# par(mfrow = c(2, 2)) # 2x2 layout of all four Histograms
# lapply(names(DF), 
#        function(x) hist(DF[, x], main = gsub("\\.", " ", x), xlab="Value"))
# When you're done: dev.off()
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. I very much doubt that this:

   ```
   hist( dataset$column1), main = "title")
   ```

   works - you have an extra bracket.
2. If you do:

   ```
    paste("dataset$column" +i )
   ```

   you will get a string "dataset$column1", etc. Instead, you need to select the column you want:

   ```
    for (i in 1:4) {
       hist(dataset[,i]  , main ="title") 
    }
   ```

   to select columns 1, 2, 3, & 4.
3. Or you could have:

   ```
    for (i in 1:4) {
       hist(dataset[[paste0("column",i)]]  , main ="title") 
    }
   ```

Comment: I doubt that you have tested this usage: `dataset$column[,i]`

Comment: And I doubt you tested this either: `dataset[paste0(column,i)]`

Comment: @DWin Moral of the story, don't answer questions as you rush out of the office. You end up being snarky and wrong!

Answer (score 1):

The `for` function is not capitalized. And the "`+`" operator does not work on character values. And you cannot append number to column name "stems" in the manner you are attempting, but you can calculate arguments to the "`[[`" operator which is what the "`$`" operator really is. This might work depending on what the column names of 'dataset' really are:

```
for (i in 1:4) {
  hist( dataset[[ paste0("column", i ) ]]  , main ="title") 
}
```

Comment: Thank you @mrdwab. This was just another instance of Skitt's law